# __init__() takes 1 positional argument but 2 were given

Tags: python-3.x

Me estoy iniciando en POO y me encuentro bloqueado con este ejemplo. Con las preguntas que he visto, para este mismo mensaje de error,  no he sido capaz de encontrar la explicación a este error.

```
class Catalogo:
    def __init__(self):
        self.peliculas = []

    def agregar(self, pelicula):  
        self.peliculas.append(pelicula)

    def mostrar(self):
        for pelicula in self.peliculas:
            print(pelicula)  # Print toma por defecto str(peicula)

pelicula1 = Catalogo ("El Padrino") 
pelicula2 = Catalogo ("El Padrino: Parte 2") 
#Catalogo.agregar("El Padrino")
#Catalogo.agregar("El Padrino: Parte 2")  # Añadimos otra
Catalogo.mostrar()
```

¿A qué se debe este error?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

El constructor que definiste solo recibe `self` como parametro.... que será rellenado con la instancia que se está creando en ese momento por python lo cual implica que no se esperan parámetros en la llamada... pero tú estás llamando pasando un parámetro que parece el título de la película? Ese tendría que ser un segundo parámetro en `__init__`:

```
def __init__(self, titulo):
    self.peliculas = []
    self.agregar(titulo)
```

podría ser que lo pongas como None por defecto, para que la llamadas la puedas hacer con o sin titulo:

```
def __init__(self, titulo = None):
    self.peliculas = []
    if titulo is not None:
        self.agregar(titulo)
```